# Text from my <main> tag is in my <header> tag, can't figure out how to get it between my header and footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build basic website, I'm having problems with text in main tag overlapping with header tag.  I've created other simple webpages before and I've never had this problem, I thought that the text in the `<main>` tag was automatically put below the header?  I was under the impression that the HTML page went like this:

```
Header
Main
Footer
```

```css
.header-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.header-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-nav li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px;
  25px;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.header-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.dota2icon img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.bodytext {
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->

  <div class="dota2icon">
    <img src="dota2icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="header-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="categories.html">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="item.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="myItems.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR END -->
</header>


<main>
  <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
  <div class="bodytext">
    <h1>Dota 2 Guides</h1>
    <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </p>
  </div>

</main>



<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Your footer is a `<div>` fo class `footer` not a `<footer>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`.header-nav` is floating right, which means that all the content that follows it and doesn't `clear` it will bubble up beside it.

Look into `clear`. Or look at not using `float` for layout (we have Flexbox and Grid now).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add clear both to you main it will solve the problem...
in your css add

```
main{
    clear: both;
}
```

**Working Sample**

```css
<style type="">
 .header-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.row {
   max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.header-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header-nav li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px; 25px;
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.header-nav li.active a {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.header-nav li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.dota2icon img {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.bodytext {
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

main{
 clear: both;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
<title>Dota 2 Guides</title>
<meta name="description" content="Project">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- DONT CHANGE, THIS IS THE LINK TO THE CSS STYLESHEET -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Project.js"></script>
</head>

<body>    
<header>
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->

    <div class="dota2icon">
    <img src="dota2icon.png">
    </div>
<div class="row">    
<ul class = "header-nav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="categories.html">Categories</a></li>
<li><a href="item.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="myItems.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR END --> 
 </header>


<main>
    <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
<div class = "bodytext">
    <h1>Dota 2 Guides</h1>
    <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </p>
    </div>

</main>



    <div class = "footer">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are fine with the `<header>` being a static height you could simply set that.

```
header {
  height: 50px;
}
```